# share images through android app on facebook hike google plus

Tags: android, facebook, share

I have created a simple android app with grid view in which user click on the image and share options available on phones displayed on the screen and user can select one from the available options. But images are only shared on watsapp and not any other options such as viber, facebook, hike etc. Here is my code what i have done wrong in it please let me know so i can overcome this issue.

```
    GridView localGridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
localGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
localGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAnonymousAdapterView, View paramAnonymousView, int paramAnonymousInt, long paramAnonymousLong)
  {
    Uri localUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://rj.hello.app1/drawable/ad_" + (paramAnonymousInt + 1));
    Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
    localIntent.setType("image/*");
    localIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", localUri);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(localIntent,MainActivity.this.getResources().getText(R.string.share)));
  }
});
```

}

images are shared on google+ and watsapp not on facebook- error message is "could not load media" and on hike, viber error message is unsupported format.
FORMAT of the images are jpeg used in the android app